# How to mock system libraries in iOS Swift without using any mocking libraries?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write unit tests for my personal project being written in Swift 2.2. A part of that project is a custom class `LocalStorageManager` which uses NSFileManager to perform file IO operations and expose very simplified file interactions for rest of the app to access. Now I am required to mock NSFileManager because I don't want my tests to create real files. I've been trying something but I don't like it.

I wrote a mock class in following format:

```
import Foundation

class MockNSFileManager: NSFileManager {

    override init() {
        // do nothings master!!
    }

    override func createFileAtPath(path: String, contents data: NSData?, attributes attr: [String : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        print("file mock created")
        return true
    }

    override func fileExistsAtPath(path: String, isDirectory: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool {
        print("does the file exists?")
        return false
    }

    override func fileExistsAtPath(path: String) -> Bool {
        print("the file exists")
        return true
    }

    override func createDirectoryAtPath(path: String, withIntermediateDirectories createIntermediates: Bool, attributes: [String : AnyObject]?) throws {
        print("successfully maybe...")
    }

    override func contentsAtPath(path: String) -> NSData? {
        print("returning some fancy contents")
        return NSData()
    }

    override func removeItemAtPath(path: String) throws {
        print("removing item at the path")
    }
}
```

In `LocalStorageManager`, I implemented an `init(fileManager: NSFileManager)`

In my unit tests, I initialize LocalStorage as `LocalStorage(fileManager: MockNSFileManager())`.

Everything is working well and as expected. However, I don't like how my test codes are invading my app production code. In `LocalStorage` class I don't like how I need to implement an `init` when my app doesn't require it to run.

I am looking for a way to make it such that I can inject mock system libraries into my custom class to facilitate testing without actually letting test codes invade main app codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! In `LocalStorage` class I previously instantiated NSFileManager as `fileMgr = NSFileManager()` in the initializer. I changed the initializer as `init(fileManager: NSFileManager)` and assigned the NSFileManager instance to `fileMgr`. I had to replace calls to `LocalStorage()` throughout the code with `LocalStorage(NSFileManager())`. Now in tests I simply initialize LocalStorage with a mock NSFileManager like `LocalStorage(MockNSFileManager())`. This works because technically, `MockNSFileManager` is a `NSFileManager` because of the line

`class MockNSFileManager: NSFileManager {`

in MockFileManager class declaration.